# Resize a memory mapped file on windows without invalidating pointers

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-mapping

I would like to resize a memory mapped file on windows, without invalidating the pointer retrieved from a previous call to `MapViewOfFileEx`. This way, all pointers to any file data that are stored throughout the application are not invalidated by the resize operation.

I found a solution for the problem but im not sure whether this approach is actually guaranteed to work in all cases.

This is my approach:
I reserve a large memory region with `VirtualAlloc`:

```
reserved_pages_ptr = (char*)VirtualAlloc(nullptr, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
base_address = reserved_pages_ptr;
```

Every time the memory map is resized, I close the old file mapping, release the reserved pages and reserve the rest pages, that are not needed for the current size of the file:

```
filemapping_handle = CreateFileMappingW(...);

SYSTEM_INFO info;
GetSystemInfo(&info);
const DWORD page_size = info.dwAllocationGranularity;

const DWORD pages_needed = file_size / page_size + size_t(file_size % page_size != 0);

// release reserved pages:
VirtualFree(reserved_pages_ptr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
// reserve rest pages:
reserved_pages_ptr = (char*)VirtualAlloc(
    base_address + pages_needed * page_size, 
    MAX_FILE_SIZE - pages_needed * page_size, 
    MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS
);

if(reserved_pages_ptr != base_address + pages_needed * page_size)
{
    //I hope this never happens...
}
```

Then i can map the view with `MapViewOfFileEx`:

```
data_ = (char*)MapViewOfFileEx(filemapping_handle, ... , base_address);

if (data_ != base_address)
{
    //I hope this also never happens...    
}
```

Is this approach stable enough to guarantee, that the potential problems never occur? 
Do I need any synchronization to avoid problems with multithreading?

EDIT: I know that the most stable approach would be to change the rest of the application to allow invalidating all the file data pointers, but this solution could be an easy approach that mirrors the behavior of `mmap` on Linux.

Comment: The question about synchronization is irrelative to the problem. In theory, MapViewOfFile will reuse the same base. However, why do you need such assurance?

Comment: Pointers to file data are "all over the place" in the application, this is why a stable pointer solution would extremely simplify adding resize capabilities to the system.

Comment: I guess that the most reliable way is a function that returns the pointer, so your pointers are replaced with that function call.

Comment: Why don't you keep the pointers as offsets from the base of the map instead?

Comment: This would of course be possible, its just a matter of simplicity. The `mmap` function on Linux actually allows memorymapping a large region and resizing the file as needed.

Comment: are your section is file or memory only based ?

Comment: if memory only  - you need use `SEC_RESERVE` flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution depends on whether you use file mapping object is backed by the operating system paging file (the hFile parameter is `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`), or by some file on disk.

In this case, you use file mapping object is backed by the operating system paging file, you need use the [**`SEC_RESERVE`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw) flag:

> specifies that when a view of the file is mapped into a process
>   address space, the entire range of pages is reserved for later use by
>   the process rather than committed. Reserved pages can be committed to
>   subsequent calls to the **VirtualAlloc** function. After the pages are
>   committed, they cannot be freed or decommitted with the **VirtualFree**
>   function.

The code can look like:

```
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 0x10000000

void ExtendInMemorySection()
{
    if (HANDLE hSection = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 0, 
            PAGE_READWRITE|SEC_RESERVE, 0, MAX_FILE_SIZE, NULL))
    {
        PVOID pv = MapViewOfFile(hSection, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);

        CloseHandle(hSection);

        if (pv)
        {
            SYSTEM_INFO info;
            GetSystemInfo(&info);

            PBYTE pb = (PBYTE)pv;
            int n = MAX_FILE_SIZE / info.dwPageSize;
            do 
            {
                if (!VirtualAlloc(pb, info.dwPageSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE))
                {
                    break;
                }

                pb += info.dwPageSize;

            } while (--n);
            UnmapViewOfFile(pv);
        }
    }
}
```

But from **`SEC_RESERVE`**

> This attribute has no effect for file mapping objects that are backed
>   by executable image files or data files (the hfile parameter is a
>   handle to a file).

For this (and only this) case exists undocumented API:

```
NTSYSCALLAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtExtendSection(
    _In_ HANDLE SectionHandle,
    _Inout_ PLARGE_INTEGER NewSectionSize
    );
```

This API lets you extend section size (and backed file). Also, `SectionHandle` must have `SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE` access right in this case, but `CreateFileMapping` creates a section handle without this access. So we need use only [`NtCreateSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) here, then we need use [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) api with `AllocationType = MEM_RESERVE` and `ViewSize = MAX_FILE_SIZE` - this reserve `ViewSize` region of memory but not commit it, but after calling `NtExtendSection` the valid data (commit pages) in view will be auto extended. 
Before win 8.1, the `MapViewOfFile` not such functionality for the pass `MEM_RESERVE` allocation type to `ZwMapViewOfSection`, but begin from win 8 (or 8.1) exist undocumented flag `FILE_MAP_RESERVE` which let do this.

In general, demonstration code can look like:

```
#define MAX_FILE_SIZE 0x10000000

void ExtendFileSection()
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"d:/ee.tmp", GENERIC_ALL, 0, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        HANDLE hSection;

        SYSTEM_INFO info;
        GetSystemInfo(&info);
        // initially only 1 page in the file
        LARGE_INTEGER SectionSize = { info.dwPageSize };

        NTSTATUS status = NtCreateSection(&hSection, 
            SECTION_EXTEND_SIZE|SECTION_MAP_READ|SECTION_MAP_WRITE, 0, 
            &SectionSize, PAGE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, hFile);

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            PVOID BaseAddress = 0;
            SIZE_T ViewSize = MAX_FILE_SIZE;

            //MapViewOfFile(hSection, FILE_MAP_WRITE|FILE_MAP_RESERVE, 0, 0, MAX_FILE_SIZE);
            status = ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, 0, 0, 0, 
                &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

            if (0 <= status)
            {   
                SIZE_T n = MAX_FILE_SIZE / info.dwPageSize - 1;
                do 
                {
                    SectionSize.QuadPart += info.dwPageSize;

                    if (0 > NtExtendSection(hSection, &SectionSize))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                } while (--n);

                UnmapViewOfFile(BaseAddress);
            }
            CloseHandle(hSection);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean, that i could call `NtExtendSection` anytime I want and the file will be automatically resized?

Comment: yes, if you use file based section - file will be resized inside `NtExtendSection` if new section size large comapre current file size

Comment: Thanks, RbMm! I used this for the windows side of a cross platform library: https://github.com/decodeless/mappedfile (for use in https://github.com/decodeless/writer).